# Angular 2 RC.5 Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I have an error

```
Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'
```

after update project to angular2 RC.5

app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DeprecatedFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      provide: TranslateLoader,
      useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, '/assets/i18n', '.json'),
      deps: [Http]
    }),
    ConfigurationDevicesModule,
    ConfigurationEditModule,
    ControlModule,
    ResourceEditModule,
    UniWebControlInfoModule,
    routing
],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

myComponent.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    ConfigurationDevicesComponent
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    TranslateModule
],
exports: [
    ConfigurationDevicesComponent
]
})

export class ConfigurationDevicesModule {

}
```

template html example:

```
<form [formGroup]="selectBackground">
                        <div *ngIf="backgrounds" class="form-group">
                            <h5>{{ 'CONFIGURATION_DEVICES.ALL_BACKGROUNDS' | translate }}</h5>
                            <select formControlName="selectBackgroundId">
                                <option *ngFor="let background of backgrounds" [value]="background.id">{{ 'CONFIGURATION_DEVICES.ID' | translate }} {{ background.id }} {{ 'CONFIGURATION_DEVICES.NAME' | translate }} {{ background.name }}</option>    
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

In angular 2 RC4, formGroup worked fine.

I tried to import both DeprecatedFormsModule and DFormsModule , the problem is the same . In official documentation Angular now I can not find any mention about formGroup or again changed the way of building forms?

Comment: Is `selectBackground` supposed to be a string or a property?

Comment: Is this intentional that you are using the `DeprecatedFormsModule`?

Comment: this.selectBackground = new FormGroup({
                            selectBackgroundId: this.selectBackgroundId
                        });

Comment: No, I started to test DeprecatedFormsModule because formModel did not bring results, I'm open to any solution

Comment: Use `ReactiveFormsModule` instead.

Comment: Now, formGroup is work but:

Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("              <td>{{ device.name }}</td>
                                <td class="center"><input [ERROR ->][ngModel]="device.isSelected" (ngModelChange)="selectDevice($event, device)" type="checkbox" value="{")

Answer (score 3):

**update**

`ReactiveFormsModule` needs to be added to `imports`

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule], // <<<===
   ...
 })
```

**original**

Use `ReactiveFormsModule` instead of `DeprecatedFormsModule`.

To be able to use `ngModel` with `formControlName` you need to import `FormsModule` **and** `ReactiveFormsModule`

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to import `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` from `@angular/forms` to your component and add it as directive (`directives: [REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES]`)
2. You need to import `FormsModule` from `@angular/forms` to your NgModule.