# binding angular object to model-driven form in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have created custom controls(in component class) with binding objects to form element in html, but there is an error message shown in consele that I couldnt solve, actually message makes no sense(formGroup is special key why it tries to bind it ?) here is the image that I see in developer console in chrome:[image]

form.component.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="from-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" formControlName="username" formControlName="email" (ngSubmit)="signup()">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="username" class="control-label col-md-2">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" id="username"  class="form-control" >
                <div class="alert alert-danger"
                *ngIf="!form.controls['username'].valid"
                >
                    User name is required.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="email" class="control-label col-md-2">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-danger"
            *ngIf="!from.controls['email'].valid"
            ></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="" class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

form.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl,FormGroup,Validators} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    moduleId:module.id,
    selector: 'post-message',
    templateUrl: '../../templates/postmessage.component.html'
})
export class PostComponent {
    form = new FormControl({
        username:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
        email:new FormControl('',Validators.required)
    })
    signup(){
        console.log(this.form.value);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
 @NgModule({
   imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule], // <<<===
   ...
 })
```

to the module where you are using `formGroup`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076395/angular-2-rc-5-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-for/39076881#39076881